# Output not displaying anything

Tags: java

So I have an assignment in Advanced Inheritance for Java and have the code pretty much hammered out but am having issues finishing it off and making it actually display the output. The program was split into 4 different parts and I have them listed below.

Account.java

```
public abstract class Account 
{
protected long accountNumber;
protected double accountBalance;
public long getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}
public double getAccountBalance()
{
    return accountBalance;
}
public void setAccountNumber(long number)
{
    number = accountNumber;
}
public void setAccountBalance(double balance)
{
    balance = accountBalance;
}
public void setUpAccount(long number, double  balance) //look up constructors
{
    number = accountNumber;
    balance = accountBalance;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Account Number: " + accountNumber + " Account Balance: " + accountBalance;
}
public abstract double computeInterest(int intPeriod);
}
```

Checkings.java

```
public class Checking extends Account
{
public String toString()
{
    String info =  "Checking\nAccount Number: " + accountNumber + 
                                                   "\nAccount Balance: " + accountBalance ;
    return info;
}
public Checking(long number)
{
    number = accountNumber;
}
public double computeInterest(int intPeriod) 
{
    double total = ((accountBalance - 700) * .02) * 3;
    return total;
}
}
```

Savings.java

```
public class Savings extends Account
{
private double interestRate;
public double getInterest()
{
    return interestRate;
}
public void setInterest(double inter)
{
    inter = interestRate;
}
public String toString()
{
    String info = "Savings\nAccount Number: " + accountNumber + " \nAccount Balance: " 
                                                          + accountBalance + " \nInterest Rate: " + interestRate;
    return info;
}
public Savings(long number, double interest)
{
    number = accountNumber;
    interest = interestRate;
}
public double computeInterest(int intPeriod) 
{
    double total = Math.pow((1 + interestRate), intPeriod) * accountBalance - accountBalance;
    return total;   
}
}
```

AccountArray.java

```
public class AccountArray 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Account[] refAccount = new Account[10];
        /*refAccount[0] = new Checking(100);
        refAccount[1] = new Checking(101);
        refAccount[2] = new Checking(102);
        refAccount[3] = new Checking(103);
        refAccount[4] = new Checking(104);
        refAccount[5] = new Savings(105, .02);
        refAccount[6] = new Savings(106, .02);
        refAccount[7] = new Savings(107, .02);
        refAccount[8] = new Savings(108, .02);
        refAccount[9] = new Savings(109, .02);

        refAccount[0].setAccountBalance(1000.0);
    refAccount[1].setAccountBalance(2000.0);
    refAccount[2].setAccountBalance(3000.0);
    refAccount[3].setAccountBalance(4000.0);
    refAccount[4].setAccountBalance(5000.0);
    refAccount[5].setAccountBalance(6000.0);
    refAccount[6].setAccountBalance(7000.0);
    refAccount[7].setAccountBalance(8000.0);
    refAccount[8].setAccountBalance(9000.0);
    refAccount[9].setAccountBalance(10000.0);*/
    for(int inc = 0; inc < 10; inc++ )
    {
        refAccount[0] = new Checking(100);
        refAccount[1] = new Checking(101);
        refAccount[2] = new Checking(102);
        refAccount[3] = new Checking(103);
        refAccount[4] = new Checking(104);
        refAccount[5] = new Savings(105, .02);
        refAccount[6] = new Savings(106, .02);
        refAccount[7] = new Savings(107, .02);
        refAccount[8] = new Savings(108, .02);
        refAccount[9] = new Savings(109, .02);

        refAccount[0].setAccountBalance(1000.0);
        refAccount[1].setAccountBalance(2000.0);
        refAccount[2].setAccountBalance(3000.0);
        refAccount[3].setAccountBalance(4000.0);
        refAccount[4].setAccountBalance(5000.0);
        refAccount[5].setAccountBalance(6000.0);
        refAccount[6].setAccountBalance(7000.0);
        refAccount[7].setAccountBalance(8000.0);
        refAccount[8].setAccountBalance(9000.0);
        refAccount[9].setAccountBalance(10000.0);
    }
    for(int ctr  = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
    {
        System.out.println(refAccount[ctr].toString());
    }
}

}
```

Is there something I'm like really obviously missing? It all compiles just fine but the output just displays 0s instead of the Account Numbers, Balance or Interest.

Any help would be very much appreciated since I'm running out of time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You're more likely to get answers quickly if you can narrow down the code that's giving you trouble.  If you can isolate the problem, it's easier for people to address it.

Answer (score 3):

All of your setter methods look the wrong way round, you've got them as...

```
public void setAccountNumber(long number)
{
    number = accountNumber;
}
public void setAccountBalance(double balance)
{
    balance = accountBalance;
}
```

All you're doing there is setting the parameter value, they should be...

```
public void setAccountNumber(long number)
{
    accountNumber= number;
}
public void setAccountBalance(double balance)
{
    accountBalance= balance;
}
```

You can make sure this doesn't happen my making your parameters final

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your constructors and setters You inverse your variable attribution

Ex

```
public void setAccountNumber(long number)
{
    number = accountNumber;
}
```

should be

```
public void setAccountNumber(long number)
{
    accountNumber = number;
}
```

same for all your setters and constructors

Comment: Wow how the heck did I manage that! That got that much fixed thanks!

Comment: Your compiler would have warned you, @Nexaz, when using `public void setAccountNumber(final long number)`.